# ¿Cómo puedo asignar espacios en una consulta de MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Hola amigos tengo un problema un tanto absurda verán soy nuevo en php y mysql tengo el siguiente planteamiento cuando hago una consulta a la base de datos con:

```html
 #My code
 $consulta = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = '1' "; //Esta es la consulta 
 
 $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta); 
 while($save="mysqli_fetch_array",$result) { 
          $posts = $save["posts"];
      }
```

cuando llamo la variable echo $posts Me devuelve la consulta sin problemas pero sin espacios.

Me devuelve los datos y todo normal, pero no tienen espacios entre los string los datos me los devuelve así:

## EJEMPLO DE RETORNO

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ut dolore tempore quas iste aut sit ipsam, soluta dignissimos error, adipisci, laboriosam illum? Illo porro nobis ducimus dolore, co Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ut dolore tempore quas iste aut sit ipsam, soluta dignissimos error, adipisci, laboriosam illum? Illo porro nobis ducimus dolore, co Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ut dolore tempore quas iste aut sit ipsam, soluta dignissimos error, adipisci, laboriosam illum? Illo porro nobis ducimus dolore, co Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ut dolore tempore quas iste aut sit ipsam, soluta dignissimos error, adipisci, laboriosam illum? Illo porro nobis ducimus dolore, co Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ut dolore tempore quas iste aut sit ipsam, soluta dignissimos error, adipisci, laboriosam illum? Illo porro nobis ducimus dolore, co

## COMO ME GUSTARIA

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ut dolore tempore quas iste aut sit ipsam, soluta dignissimos error, adipisci, laboriosam illum? Illo porro nobis ducimus dolore, co

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ut dolore tempore quas iste aut sit ipsam, soluta dignissimos error, adipisci, laboriosam illum? Illo porro nobis ducimus dolore, co

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ut dolore tempore quas iste aut sit ipsam, soluta dignissimos error, adipisci, laboriosam illum? Illo porro nobis ducimus dolore, co

Comment: Hola amigo recién comienzo con js pero como podría lograrlo?

Comment: son varios parrafos de hecho en la base de datos si están separados por espacios por lo que tontamente supuse que aparecerían tal cual cuando hiciera un echo a la variable que almacena los datos pero no fue así

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifica si en la BD están guardados los valores correspondientes a los saltos de linea. De ser así, los puedes recuperar de la siguiente forma.

```
echo nl2br($save["posts"]);
```

O también:

```
$posts = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br />", $save["posts"]);
echo $posts;
```

Documentación: [Función nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: Gracias amigo indagaré mas a fondo ahora no se muestran los datos pero me supongo es error en una parte de mi codigo

Comment: Eres la verg4 parada muchisimas gracias amigo :D

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes agregarle un tag 
 al terminar de dibujar cada linea con el while, ejemplo:

```html
 #My code
 $consulta = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = '1' "; //Esta es la consulta 
 
 $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta); 
 while($save="mysqli_fetch_array",$result) { 
          $posts = $save["posts"]."<br>";
      }
```

Comment: Lo del . "<br/>" Ya lo intente y no funciono por desgracia

Comment: si lo del salto de linea no me funciono lo intente antes de hacer la pregunta porque no queria quedar como un gran tonto noob pero al no dar mejor hice la pregunta,

Comment: Raro, manteniendo la lógica que te dije cambia la variable $posts por un echo, de manera que lo dibujar de forma secuencial. Quedando así: echo $save["posts"]."<br>";

Comment: Hola amigo no me funcione me retorna igual los datos

Comment: @Ale no puede funcionar, el resultado es un único registro, no varios, por lo que se estaría añadiendo un <br> al final del registro, no en los párrafos contenidos en dicho registro.

Answer (score 0):

Eso lo podes solucionar con algo de estilos css, por ejemplo...

```
<style>
.formato {
tu codigo de estilo
}
</style>

     $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta); 
     while($save="mysqli_fetch_array",$result) { 
              $posts = "<p class='formato'>".$save["posts"]."</p>";
          }
```

Comment: Gracias amigo eso ya lo habia intentado pero no me funciono utlize      
                 letter-spacing: 1px;
                  word-wrap: 10px;
                  word-spacing: 5px;
                  font-weight: 10px;
                  line-height: 30px;
                  text-indent: 10px;

Comment: que raro, recuerdo una vez que pase por algo similar y se soluciono asi, fijate bien tiene que ir por ahi lo que buscas, algo quiza no te esta tomando bien el codigo, fijate de formatear el css *{padding:0etc..}

Comment: gracias amigo volveré  a verificar el código.

Comment: @CSHKtimporta no puede funcionar, el resultado es un único registro, no varios, por lo que se estaría añadiendo un párrafo al registro, no en los párrafos contenidos en dicho registro.

Comment: Asi es, error de tipeo mio, gracias!